# Read the last N lines from logcat?

Tags: android

I'd like to read the last n lines from logcat. Should this be working?:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -t -500");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
...
```

> -t number

Makes logcat print only entries from the position indicated by number and onward. A positive number indicates that the position is relative to the beginning of the log file, and a negative number indicates that the position is relative to the end of the log file.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
String[] command = { "logcat", "-t", "500" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

For a full example check Log Collector, it definitely works:

http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/SendLogActivity.java

To explain why this works from logcat man:

```
  -t <count>      print only the most recent <count> lines (implies -d)
  -t '<time>'     print most recent lines since specified time (implies -d)
  -T <count>      print only the most recent <count> lines (does not imply -d)
  -T '<time>'     print most recent lines since specified time (not imply -d)
                  count is pure numerical, time is 'MM-DD hh:mm:ss.mmm'
```

Comment: What should I do if I need to access by time?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the stack trace after an exception occurred then you can use  `getStackTraceString(Throwable tr)` in the catch clause.

```
try {

} catch(Exception e ) {
     String crashLog = Log.getStackTraceString(e); 
     // Save crashLog to file to do something...
}
```

You can specify a filter in logcat command so that you atleast get a stripped down version of the full log.

Comment: Ah thanks for the code, I gotta get the logcat output though. I'm trying to capture log output for a user who can't get SharedPrefs.editor.commit() to work. There's no exception thrown sadly.